# Why is my public variable not behaving as expected?

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Form1

  Public diameter As Integer
  Public radius As Decimal = diameter / 2

  Private Sub TxtRadius10_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TxtRadius10.TextChanged, TxtDiameter10.TextChanged
    diameter = TxtDiameter10.Text
    TxtRadius10.Text = radius
  End Sub
End Class
```

The value in TxtRadius10 keeps coming back 0 when it should be 5 (The text in TxtDiameter10 box is 10 and locked). I know diameter is initializing because if I set TxtRadius10.Text = diameter/2, it will come back 5.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and put `Option Strict On` at the top of your code or set it in your project's properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't doing what you think it's doing:

```
Public radius As Decimal = diameter / 2
```

The `radius` variable doesn't hold a *reference* to the `diameter` variable for future calculations.  This assignment statement calculates it *once* with the *current* values and places the *result* in `radius`.  The current value of `diameter` is:

```
Public diameter As Integer
```

Well, it's unassigned.  So it's defaulting to `0`.  And `0 / 2` is `0`.  So `radius` is being initialized to `0`, and it's never assigned again in the code.  So it will always be `0`.

If you want to dynamically calculate the value every time it's accessed, make it a property:

```
Public Property radius As Decimal
    Get 
        Return diameter / 2
    End Get 
End Property
```

Now any reference to `radius` will run the `Get` logic whenever it's accessed and re-calculate the value on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You've got yourself an unintended loop.

When you change the value of TxtRadius10.Text in the TxtRadius10_TextChanged event, it fires off the event again. Since diameter starts off as 0 (the default value of an integer), the radius value starts off as 0 (0 / 2).

You should also know that Radius is not going to update when you update diameter. You've just set an initial value for it. You've got to recalculate the radius whenever diameter changes.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring radius = diameter/ 2
However diameter isn't defined when it comes across this statement.

Define diameter first before defining radius